# 2sxc: can not install any apps

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, 2sxc

I have recently installed the latest version of the base app from codeplex (2sic_2SexyContent_08.04.08_Install.zip ) to DNN vesion 7.4.0, created a new admin page and added the module there.

from there I have tried to add a new app (2sxcApp_GoogleTagManager_01.00.01.zip) and the install pop up flashes for a split second then nothing happens.

checking the console I see;

```
/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/dnn/ui.html?sxcver=8.4.8.19191#zoneI…true&user%5BcanDevelop%5D=true&approot=%2F&dialog=dash-view&items=%5B%5D:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://northcityosteopaths.co.nz/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableApps. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/dnn/ui.html?sxcver=8.4.8.19191#zoneI…rue&user%5BcanDevelop%5D=true&approot=%2F&dialog=app-import&items=%5B%5D:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://northcityosteopaths.co.nz/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app/ImportExport/ImportApp. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kI6i.png)

I have tried reinstalling the base module and recycling the app pool
have also set page skin to default Gravity skin.

Comment: I've never seen this before, my guess is that it could have something to do with different protocolls (http vs. https) or different main domains (incomplete config in dnn). Could you verify that both the source protocol and domain are the same as the api call?

Comment: @iJungleBoy
As we only have http and don't use https at all on our server I am pretty confidant that isn't the issue.

when you say different main domains/incomplete config in DNN can you clarfiy where/what I should be looking for? This dnn install has been updae running for sometime and we have installed a great many DNN Modules but this is the first time we have tried adding "apps" in this manner pigyy backing of a base module.

Comment: best to watch the wire with fiddler or something and compare the original domain you're on with the one used in the js-calls. If a dnn config isn't quite right, then the dnn-js-framework will use a different domain for the js-calls, which would cause such errors.

Comment: just for clarification: the error you are seeing has to do with something related to javascript-upload and security.